# Не отображает переменную в виджите tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. При запуске нового окна не отрабатывают виджеты, которые должны в нём создаваться (функция info). Подскажите, что не так делаю? 
Я знаю, что в label можно использовать просто text, а не через переменную.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

sequence = ['5','6','7','8','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k']

def get_pwd(*args):
    value = StringVar()
    value.set("".join([random.choice(sequence) for _ in range(5)]))
    messagebox.showwarning(message=f'Password: {value.get()}', title="Get password")

def info(*args):
    new_window = Toplevel(root)
    new_window.title("author information")
    additional_fr = ttk.Frame(new_window, padding="10 10 10 10")
    additional_fr.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    value = StringVar()
    value.set(u"Иванов Иван Иванович")
    ttk.Label(additional_fr, textvariable=value).grid(row=1, sticky=N, padx=10, pady=10)


root = Tk()
root.title("Random Password Generator")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="generate",
           command=get_pwd).grid(row=1, sticky=N, padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="author information",
           command=info).grid(row=2, sticky=N, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: если использовать `text=value.get()` , то работает. Не понятно почему не работает textvariable.

Comment: Такое впечатление что `ttk.Label` не работает с переменными. Попробуйте просто `Label` без `ttk`.

Comment: @insolor Если смотреть [туториал](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html) из документации, то там как рза это используют `meters= StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))`

Comment: @insolor Пример из туториала я запускал, он отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Там переменная меняется из обработчика нажатия, а у вас сразу после создания Label, возможно в этом причина. Вообще в данном случае нет особого смысла в использовании переменной.

Comment: я понимаю, что нет смысла тут так делать. Вопрос в том, что почему не работает. И так должно работать, грубо говоря мы делаем значение по-умолчанию и в дальнейшем, если понадобится, то меняем